# Bash prompt getting garbled when I browse history?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal, command-history, prompt

I have MacOS and `.bash_profile` content:

`export PS1="\[\e[0;31m$\]\[\e[m\] \[\e[0;32m\w\e[m\] : \]"`

as a result I have pwd printed in terminal like this:

[image: Screen capture]

but when I press up and down arrows to use terminal history I have bug:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. no need to export PS1: it's a variable for the shell, other processes aren't going to use it.
2. looks like you don't have the escaping brackets quite right. They are there to surround *non-printing* sequences, so bash can accurately figure how wide your prompt is. Try this:

   ```
   PS1="\[\e[0;31m\]\$ \[\e[0;32m\]\w\[\e[0m\] : "
   #     1.........1    2.........2   3......3
   ```

   So the printing bits (`\$`, `\w`, the colon and the spaces) are **outside** the brackets.

Further reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt

Comment: Thanks for blazing fast answer! You saved my day!