# SSH terminal messes multiline commands

Tags: bash, ssh, openssh

I am frequently using ssh terminal. If I enter a command that spans multiple lines, the characters which do not fit onto the first line are going to the beginning... not of the next but of the current line! As if no \n, but just \r was inserted. This get even more messed up when I am scrolling up the history, as the terminal starts to delete previously output lines, and if I delete some characters in a previously used multiline command, not only that character but a whole previous line gets deleted.  The bash version on the server I am connecting to is 2.05b.0(1) (yep, that old - ask our server administrator). SSH version is OpenSSH 7.4.

Comment: Looks like a `PS1`-related problem. See this: [*Bash prompt getting garbled when I browse history*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/494147/108618).

Comment: Or maybe `$PS2`. Please do this: `$ echo -n $PS2 | hexdump -C` and the same for `$PS1` and put the results into the question (formatted as `code`, please)

Comment: Yes, thank you all! It was precisely the problem of using PS1 and not using many enough \\[ \\].